# vue-progressbar in vuex typeError

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I've just started to learn vue and vuex.

I want to use the progressbar from [this link](https://github.com/hilongjw/vue-progressbar)

Like the description said I imported the `main.js` file into my `actions.js`

```
import app from '../../../main'  //This is causing the error
```

so I could use this just before my **axios-request**:

```
 app.$Progress.start()
```

The `main.js` file:

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window._ = require('lodash')

    require('admin-lte');
    require('bootstrap')
} catch (e) {}

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store/index'
import VueProgressBar from 'vue-progressbar'
import swal from 'sweetalert2'
import moment from 'moment'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(VueProgressBar, {
    color: 'rgb(143,255,199)',
    failedcolor: 'red',
    height: '5px'
})

Vue.use(require('vue-moment'))
Vue.use(moment)

window.bus = new Vue()
window.swal = swal;

const toast = swal.mixin({
    toast: true,
    position: 'top-end',
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 3500
})

window.toast = toast

export default new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

This is working, but I'm getting errors when working on those pages.

> ( "TypeError: _main__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default is
>   undefined")

**Edit: Updated the `main.js` file**

So my question is how do I fix this?

Comment: Can you please edit to show your full main.js file?

Comment: @arapl3y Edited the post with the complete main.js file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of the modules you are importing does export anything default, can you check/include your store and router files?

```
export default {...} //Missing from one of the modules
```